Is there a way to create different css files for dark/light tailwind
I have a NextJS project, I am using tailwind and my project suffers from ver large sized css files. Around 65KB. I want to split light and dark mode css files. Is there any webpack plugin for this? or is there any way I compile tailwind through CLI and generate different CSS files for light and dark mode? The dark mode css file contains only those styles that are declared using dark: variant, and light mode contains all other styles.
I tried using tailwind css CLI but it does not have any such option.

There is no built-in option to do this.

@Wongjn is there any webpack plugin that does this?

I don't know. You could look at writing some custom build plugin somewhere that does what you want.
